# Extending Core Controller without Custom Module

Tags: admin-controller

I want to extend a core controller:

app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\CustomerController.php

I simply want to customise the one of the functions. I have created the following file:

app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\CustomerController.php

My class is as follows:

class Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController

All of the examples I have found similar to this metion the need to add an entry into my config.xml. But in my case this is not part of a cutom module since it is in the dir which mirrors the core - in local.

I simply want the customer controller to execute as well as my entension of it. If I add a die() in my extended controller class it doesn't fire. I have flushed the cache and logged out and back into admin.

What am I doing worng?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom class name should be same as original.

Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController

Comment: apologies that was a typo in my question, it is named the same as the core controller - see my revised question

Comment: Can you check if compilation mode is disabled? http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/system-tools-compilation.html